# R trying to bin with group_by and summarise, but output full of NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, binning

I have a long tibble with 3 columns. Example:

| **Spectrum** | **Mass** | **Intensity** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spectrum A | 14.1 | 5 |
| Spectrum A | 14.2 | 3 |
| Spectrum A | 14.1 | 20 |
| Spectrum A | 20.3 | 7 |
| Spectrum B | 11.7 | 4 |
| Spectrum B | 13.4 | 5 |
| Spectrum B | 33.0 | 5 |
| Spectrum B | 33.1 | 10 |
| … | … | … |
| Spectrum Z | n | n |

For each **Spectrum**, I wish to round the **Mass** values to the nearest integer. Then, if there are multiple entries of the same integer Mass, only keep the row with the highest **Intensity** value.

Example desired output:

| **Spectrum** | **Mass** | **Intensity** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spectrum A | 14 | 20 |
| Spectrum A | 20 | 7 |
| Spectrum B | 12 | 4 |
| Spectrum B | 13 | 5 |
| Spectrum B | 33 | 10 |
| … | … | … |
| Spectrum Z | n | n |

To do this, I thought this code should work:

```
df_binned <- df %>%
  mutate(Mass = round(Mass, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Spectrum, Mass) %>%
  summarise(Intensity = max(Intensity)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Unfortunately, the actual output's **Intensity** is almost fully NAs. For many Spectrums, it's 100% NAs. I have verified that the **Mass** and **Intensity** columns are indeed numerics, not characters.

Does anyone know why this is happening? And/or how can I implement this "binning" transformation?

Comment: Have you tried `summarise(Intensity = max(Intensity, na.rm = TRUE))`? Otherwise even a single missing value in the group will cause the whole group to be NA

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, you are right! Could you please re-submit as an Answer so I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Mass = round(Mass, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Spectrum, Mass) %>%
  summarise(Intensity = max(Intensity, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Otherwise even a single missing value in a group will cause the whole group to be `NA`